# GetProcAddress() does not load the function from the dll

Tags: c++, winapi, dllimport

I need to import the dll function into my project and use it.
However, when importing it into my project with GetProcAddress() function it does not seem to work. Function returns null and the simple if check finishes the program.

I'm pretty sure there is some problem with my code, but I don't seem to be able to find it. Here is the code of Library.h file

```
#pragma once

#include <iostream>
#include <windows.h>
#include <string>
#include <cmath>
using namespace std;

#ifdef MY_DLL_EXPORTS

#define MY_DLL_API extern "C" _declspec(dllexport)

#else 

#define MY_DLL_API extern "C" _declspec(dllimport)

#endif

struct args
{
    int Elements;
    int sum;
    int* Array;
};

DWORD WINAPI NoSynchroSum(LPVOID);
void Monitoring(int);
```

Library.cpp file

```
#include "pch.h"
#include "framework.h"
#include "Library.h"
using namespace std;

DWORD WINAPI NoSynchroSum(LPVOID arg)
{
    args* _args = (args*)arg;
    for (int i = 0; i < _args->Elements; i++)
    {
        _args->sum += _args->Array[i];
    }
    return 0;
}

void Monitoring(int Elements)
{
    int ElementsAmount = Elements;
    HANDLE handle;
    int suspendCount = 1;
    int sum = 0;
    srand(time(0));
    int* Array = new int[ElementsAmount];
    for (int i = 0; i < ElementsAmount; i++)
    {
        Array[i] = rand() % 21 - 10;
    }
    args* _args = new args;
    _args->Elements = ElementsAmount;
    _args->sum = sum;
    _args->Array = Array;
    handle = CreateThread(NULL, 0, NoSynchroSum, (LPVOID)_args, NULL, NULL);
    cout << "Counted Sum = " << sum << endl;
    CloseHandle(handle);
    delete[] Array;
    delete _args;
}
```

And my other project code, where i'm trying to import and use the function

```
#include <iostream>
#include <Windows.h>
using namespace std;

int main() {

    HINSTANCE hInstance = LoadLibrary(L"D:\\Visual Studio 2022\\repos\\LabOS_7_DLL\\x64\\Debug\\DLLibrary.dll");

    if (!hInstance) {

        std::cout << "Library not loaded.\n";
        return 1;
    }

    void (*pMainFunc)(int);
    pMainFunc = (void(*)(int))GetProcAddress(hInstance, "Monitoring"); // експорт функції створення потоку
    if (!pMainFunc) 
    {
        std::cout << "Function not loaded.\n";
        return 1;
    }
    int ElementsAmount = 0;
    while (true)
    {
        cout << "enter size of array: ";
        cin >> ElementsAmount;
        if (ElementsAmount < 100)
        {
            cout << "size of array must be >=100\n";
            continue;
        }
        break;
    }
    pMainFunc(ElementsAmount);
    FreeLibrary(hInstance);

    return 0;
}
```

Comment: Did you try `dumpbin` on your dll to see if the functions are there? Presumably you are getting as output `"Function not loaded."`? Did you see what `GetLastError` returns?

Comment: What does `dumpbin /EXPORTS ...\DLLibrary.dll` yield?

Comment: Ouch, that's an uncomfortable amount of macros, casts, pointers and similar. Are we back in the 1990's or are we writing modern C++?

Comment: @fabian I'm not sure if it's supposed to look like this, as it's my first time working with dlls
Dump of file DLLibrary.dll

File Type: DLL

  Summary

        1000 .00cfg
        1000 .data
        2000 .idata
        1000 .msvcjmc
        3000 .pdata
        4000 .rdata
        1000 .reloc
        1000 .rsrc
        A000 .text
       10000 .textbss

Comment: @JesperJuhl so sorry about that, but I'm writing my code according to the code, that my teacher provided. Ik that it may be outdated, but I only need to use it for this one task

Comment: You created a `MY_DLL_API` macro but then forgot to actually use it.

Comment: Dll is x86 ? About name mangling you never listen ? You never listen about pe viewers and not try look what names is exported exactly?

Comment: @fuvaji Seems your teacher is stuck in the past. You may want to look for better teaching resources.

Comment: `args* _args = (args*)arg;` - Ouch.

Comment: You need to mark the function as exported.

Answer (score 0):

I test the code and get the GetLastError:127 ERROR_PROC_NOT_FOUND:The specified procedure could not be found.

It means that there is no exported function with that name.

I suggest you should use the following code in the `Library.h`:

```
MY_DLL_API DWORD WINAPI NoSynchroSum(LPVOID);
MY_DLL_API  void Monitoring(int);
```